# Getting null values in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, null

Using PowerShell, I have code that will count the number of times a value appears anywhere in a .csv file. If I put `"\bhello\b"`, it will count the times "hello" appears anywhere in the .csv. The problem is that it doesn't work for counting the times null appears in the CSV. It gives me a number bigger than the number of values in the entire CSV file.

```
(select-string -Path 'D:\AaronR\Desktop\Book.csv' -Pattern "\b$null\b" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches).Count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your regular expression:

- You defined your pattern as a double quoted string `\b$null\b`, so PowerShell automatically expands the variable `$null` to a null value and casts that to an empty string (to fit it into the string). Because of this you're effectively matching a pattern `\b\b`.
- The character `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions (the end of a string), so it must be escaped (`\$`) in order to match a literal `$` character.
- The character `$` isn't a word-character, so even when escaping the `$` the pattern `\b\$word\b` will only match if you have a word-character right *before* the `$` (e.g. `something$null`).

If you want to match literal strings `$null` in your CSV you need to escape the `$` and put the first word boundary marker between `$` and `n`. Also, I'd recommend to use single quotes for regular expression strings, unless you want variables expanded in them.

```
Select-String -Pattern '\$\bnull\b' ...
```